# In inter-domain routing, what methods can I used to specify the set of the ASes that will be traversed?

Tags: routing, internet, rfc

In RFC 4655, Page 5, the author wrote, "*...the path of an inter-AS TE LSP may be computed using a PCE-based path computation model in some ASes, whereas the set of traversed ASes may be specified by other means (not determined by a PCE).*" My question is: what means can I used to specify or choose the ASes that should be traversed to reach the destination?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. You have no control over what other ASes do with traffic sent to them. That is the whole point of an AS (Autonomous System); they are autonomous. You would not want someone in a different AS telling you what to do in your AS, and it works both ways.

Having said that, it is entirely possible that multiple, neighboring ASes may come to a business arrangement as to how traffic will be routed through the ASes. This is something that does happen.

[*RFC 4655, A Path Computation Element (PCE)-Based Architecture*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4655.txt) is an Informational RFC, not a Standards Track RFC. You must read the entire RFC. There are sections that explain that you may not have the visibility or control:

> There are several scenarios where the node responsible for path
>   computation has limited visibility of the network topology to the
>   destination.  This limitation may occur, for instance, when an ingress
>   router attempts to establish a TE LSP to a destination that lies in a
>   separate domain, since TE information is not exchanged across the
>   domain boundaries.  In such cases, it is possible to use loose routes
>   to establish the TE LSP, relying on routers at the domain borders to
>   establish the next piece of the path.  However, it is not possible to
>   guarantee that the optimal (shortest) path will be used, or even that
>   a viable path will be discovered except, possibly, through repeated
>   trial and error using crankback or other signaling extensions.
>
> This problem of inter-domain path computation may most probably be
>   addressed through distributed computation with cooperation among PCEs
>   within each of the domains, and potentially using crankback between
>   the domains to dynamically resolve provisioning issues. Alternatively,
>   a central "all-seeing" PCE that has access to the complete set of
>   topology information may be used, but in this case there are
>   challenges of scalability (both the size of the TED and the
>   responsiveness of a single PCE handling requests for many domains) and
>   of preservation of confidentiality when the domains belong to
>   different Service Providers.